# Javascript maximum call stack

Tags: javascript, stack, max, call

Hi everyone I created two functions for my music playlist,

- one that goes to the next music
- one passing to a random music

I am aware that my code is not as clean and functional as possible but it works pretty good,

Only an error occurs when i click next until the last music **6 times** in my example but then when I click on random, an error **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded appears**, without knowing why, here is my code:

[Test](http://jsdo.it/rdnry/9V5B/fullscreen)

```
var array = {
   0: {
    "id" : 1,
       "nom" : "Musique 1",
       "durée" : "3m34"
   },
   1: {
    "id" : 2,
       "nom" : "Musique 2",
       "durée" : "2m32"
   },
   2: {
        "id" : 3,
       "nom" : "Musique 3",
          "durée" : "3m54"
   },
   3: {
    "id" : 4,
       "nom" : "Musique 4",
       "durée" : "2m19"
   },
   4: {
    "id" : 5,
       "nom" : "Musique 5",
       "durée" : "2m24"
   },
   5: {
    "id" : 6,
       "nom" : "Musique 6",
       "durée" : "1m58"
   }
};
var count = getObjectLength(array), itmsl = [], mus = -1;

function aleatoire(p){
      var item = Math.floor(Math.random()*count);
      mus = item;
      if(itmsl.indexOf(item) < 0){
        itmsl.push(item);
        echo(array[item]);             
      }else{
        aleatoire();               
      }
      if(itmsl.length >= count){
        itmsl = [];
      }
}
function suivant(){
    mus++;
    if(itmsl.indexOf(mus) < 0 && typeof array[mus] !== 'undefined'){
      itmsl.push(mus);
      echo(array[mus]);
    }else{
      mus = -1;
      itmsl = [];
      suivant();
    }
}
function echo(str){
    if(typeof str != "undefined"){
        console.log(str);
    }else console.log('error');
}

function getObjectLength(obj){
    var length = 0;
    for ( var p in obj ){
      if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( p ) ){
        length++;
      }
    }
  return length;
}
```

Thank's for the help

Comment: What is the exact purpose of aleatoire() and suivant()?

Comment: @Cranio: He should have said, but "aleatoire" means "random" and suivant means "next" (in this context). It's French.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, the meaning in French what somewhat understandable for me, but I meant from a detailed functional point of view. Which are the use cases?

Comment: Rather than linking to one of the many live demo sites, it would be better to use Stack Overflow's **own** Stack Snippets to produce the [MCVE](/help/mcve). They're the `<>` button in the toolbar. Ensures that all relevant code is **in** the question (not just linked) and that it's easy to copy to answers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The function `suivant()` neither accepts arguments nor does it return a value. It therefore seems to me that it's uselessly recursive (the whole point of recursion is to use the call stack to manage your data storage but you seem to already manage it manually using an array). The only reason it's written the way it is seems to be to emulate a `goto`.

Therefore it's very trivial to change it to a `while` loop (which is of course just another form of goto):

```
function suivant(){
    var end = 0;

    while (!end) {
        mus++;
        if(itmsl.indexOf(mus) < 0 && typeof array[mus] !== 'undefined'){
            end = 1;
            itmsl.push(mus);
            echo(array[mus]);
        }else{
            mus = -1;
            itmsl = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly, the function `aleatoire` should also be iterative:

```
function aleatoire(){
    var end = 0;

    while (!end) {
        var item = Math.floor(Math.random()*count);
        mus = item;
        if(itmsl.indexOf(item) < 0){
            end = 1;
            itmsl.push(item);
            echo(array[item]);             
        } else {
            // don't end
        }
        if(itmsl.length >= count){
            itmsl = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move your recursion breaker to the top, it should work ie . in your aleatoire method move this code to the top . You don't really need recursion at all once you do that and can safely comment out the else

```
 function aleatoire(){
          if(itmsl.length >= count){
            itmsl = [];
          }
          var item = Math.floor(Math.random()*count);
          mus = item;
          if(itmsl.indexOf(item) < 0){
            itmsl.push(item);
            echo(array[item]);             
          }
//else{
       //     aleatoire();               
        //  }

    }
```

The same can be applied to the suviant method too .

Comment: I think that aleatoire() is meant as a sort of shuffle method